# How to use tasklist command with an array?

Tags: windows, cmd

I'm working on a cmd script and want to find some processes in the tasklist. So what I have is an array like "prog[0]=devcpp.exe, prog[1]=notepad.exe..."
And to find these processes I'm using FOR command. Ok, but when I execute the command "tasklist /fi" it seems won't recognize the array, and don't give me the expected result.

The code is:

```
set prog[0]=devcpp.exe
set prog[1]=notepad.exe
set prog[2]=calc.exe

FOR /l %%a IN (0,1,2) DO (
     tasklist /fi "IMAGENAME eq %prog[%%a]%"
)
```

But the result is:

```
error: the search filter cannot be recognized
```

And of course I am running these processes...
So, any suggestions?

Comment: "Any suggestions?" Yes. Use PowerShell instead, which has proper arrays.

Answer (score 1):

First, remove the trailing QUOTATION MARK character on the `prog[2]` setting.

Secondly, when invoking `tasklist`, the PERCENT character must be doubled to retain one. And, use the command line interpreter. `%ComSpec%`, to interpret the variable.

```
set prog[0]=devcpp.exe
set prog[1]=notepad.exe
set prog[2]=powershell.exe

FOR /l %%a IN (0,1,2) DO (
    "%ComSpec%" /C tasklist /fi "IMAGENAME eq %%prog[%%a]%%"
)
```

You have given no clue as to what the end goal is about. It would likely be easier to code this in PowerShell as @Bill_Stewart suggested.

Comment: Oh, I miss that quotation..
I'll try with double % and %comspec%. Didn't know about it.  
Thanks.

Comment: or `call tasklist /fi "IMAGENAME eq %%prog[%%a]%%"` or (with delayed expansion): `tasklist /fi "IMAGENAME eq !prog[%%a]!"`

Answer (score -1):

Here is my suggestion for this task with a commented batch file.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
rem Delete all environment variables of which name starts with prog[.
for /F "delims==" %%I in ('set prog[ 2^>nul') do set "%%I="

rem Define environment variables with the executables to get listed.
set "prog[0]=devcpp.exe"
set "prog[1]=notepad.exe"
set "prog[2]=calc.exe"

rem Run TASKLIST in a loop to get output a list of those processes
rem from the list defined above which are currently running with the
rem header output on English Windows just on first running process.
set "Header=1"
for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%I in ('set prog[') do if defined Header (
    %SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe /FI "IMAGENAME eq %%J" 2>&1 | %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /B /I /L /V /C:"INFO:"
    if not errorlevel 1 set "Header="
) else (
    %SystemRoot%\System32\tasklist.exe /NH /FI "IMAGENAME eq %%J" 2>nul
)
endlocal
```

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `tasklist /?`